The 12th Amendment: what if the presidential and vice-presidential candidates are from the same state?
The first clause of the first sentence of Amendment 12 of the U.S. Constitution is a puzzling construction.

The electors shall meet in their respective States and vote by ballot for President and Vice-President, one of whom, at least, shall not be an inhabitant of the same State with themselves;

What does this mean?  Suppose the Presidential and Vice-Presidential candidates are of the same state.  Electors must meet in their respective States and vote in that state.  Thus all of these people (the President and VP candidates, and the electors) will all be of the same state.
It seems a self-contradictory requirement.

I'm pretty sure I've seen a similar question in [politics.se] some time ago, but I can't find it.

Are you asking about the case where one party nominates candidates from the same state, or the case where all the candidates from all the parties are from the same state? Also, that's not correct use of "self-contradictory". "self-contradictory" means that a contradiction is obtained solely from a statement. If there is a contradiction between the statement and contingent facts (such as the states candidates are from), that's not "self-contradictory".

"Suppose...":  this is a counterfactual supposition.  Because of the quoted provision, presidential candidates always choose a vice presidential candidate who either already resides in a different state or is willing to change residence to a different state.

This requires any elector to cast at least one of their votes for president or vice president for someone not from the state of the elector.
If the presidential and vice-presidential candidates were of the same state, the electors from that state would be unable to vote for both of them.
In practice, parties ensure their presidential and vice-presidential candidates do not come from the same state; otherwise, they risk failing to elect the ticket as a pair. This risk would present itself in a close election where the home state electors would have to split their votes.
Dick Cheney changed his residence from Texas to Wyoming to avoid this risk when being selected to be George W. Bush's running-mate.

Robert F. Kennedy Jr. and Nicole Shanahan had this problem, as they both reside in California.  Kennedy tried to remedy this by claiming he was actually a resident of New York, but the New York courts didn't believe him.  And since he had listed his residency as New York on his nominating petitions, which they determined was not true, they kicked him off the New York ballot.  Of course, they didn't have much chance of winning California's electoral votes in the first place (nor New York's for that matter).

In practice, presidential and vice-presidential candidates are selected to broaden the appeal of the ticket, and that means selecting them from different regions of the country, not to mention different states. Both candidates from the same state would be a negative to voters outside that state, and their opponents would quickly claim it would lead to undue influence of that state in national politics.


Suppose the Presidential and Vice-Presidential candidates are of the same state

The original election system was that the candidate that got the most elector votes would become the President, while the runner up would become a Vice President.
This resulted in 1796 in Thomas Jefferson becoming the VP under John Adams, despite being from the opposing party.
The amendment is designed to allow parties to nominate candidates for both the President and the VP position running on the same ticket (the system we are using today), with the condition that they're not from the same State - otherwise risking the electoral votes from their state. For example, Gavin Newsom couldn't have been Kamala Harris's VP pick due to this condition. Similarly, Matt Gaetz couldn't be Trump's VP pick (just as an example), since both states' electors would be critical for their respective elections.

Wikipedia's List of vice presidents of the United States says Aaron Burr was vice-president during Thomas Jefferson's first term as president, and George Clinton during his second. When Adams's term ended, he went back to Massachusetts.
